# General solution for subscribing to listeners in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a reusable way of subscribing to listener like keyboard events.

Actually I have a button with position absolute at the very bottom of my screen and when keyboard pops up it comes floating on top and that does not look very good.

So I am hiding that button when keyboard is visible but if you have similar scenario on multiple screens it becomes headache to add subscription on every screen currently I am doing it this way.

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this);
    this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // subscribing to keyboard listeners on didMount

    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );

    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    this.setState({
      keyboardVisible: true,
    });
  }

  _keyboardDidHide() {
    this.setState({
      keyboardVisible: false,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // unsubscribing listeners on unMount

    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    const AnimatedBottomButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(BottomButton);

    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.containerStyle}
        bounces={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        {this.renderUserImage()}
        {this.renderUserDetail()}
        {!this.state.keyboardVisible && (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            }}>
            <AnimatedBottomButton
              title="Done"
              onPress={() => Actions.pop()}
              style={{
                opacity: this.anim5,
                transform: [{ scale: this.anim5 }],
                marginBottom: Utils.isPhoneX() ? Metrics.doubleBaseMargin : 0,
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't like the above solution since I have to add subscription related code to every Component I want to subscribe for keyboard events I am new to javascript and still learning it.

If any one out there can help me with some general solution of it would be very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom components come in handy in these situations. You can create a single component with desired behaviors implemented and then you can add that component to the screens you want to use.

**Sample**

```
export default class CustomButton extends Component {
  state = {
    visible: true
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // subscribing to keyboard listeners on didMount
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => this._toggleVisiblity(false)
    );

    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => this._toggleVisiblity(true)
    );
  }
  _toggleVisiblity = (visible) => {
    this.setState({ visible })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // unsubscribing listeners on unMount

    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.visible === false) return null
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }}>
        <AnimatedBottomButton
          title="Done"
          onPress={() => Actions.pop()}
          style={{
            opacity: this.anim5,
            transform: [{ scale: this.anim5 }],
            marginBottom: Utils.isPhoneX() ? Metrics.doubleBaseMargin : 0,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.containerStyle}
        bounces={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        {this.renderUserImage()}
        {this.renderUserDetail()}
        <CustomButton />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

You can go a bit further if you like and create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

**Sample**

```
const withKeyboardEvents = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      visible: true,
    };
    componentDidMount() {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        'keyboardDidShow',
        () => this._toggleVisiblity(false)
      );
      this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        'keyboardDidHide',
        () => this._toggleVisiblity(true)
      );
    }
    _toggleVisiblity = visible => {
      this.setState({ visible });
    };
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
      this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.visible === true && (
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              }}>
              <AnimatedBottomButton
                title="Done"
                onPress={() => Actions.pop()}
                style={{
                  opacity: this.anim5,
                  transform: [{ scale: this.anim5 }],
                  marginBottom: Utils.isPhoneX() ? Metrics.doubleBaseMargin : 0,
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )}
          <WrappedComponent />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };
};
```

---

```
class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.containerStyle}
        bounces={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        {this.renderUserImage()}
        {this.renderUserDetail()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
export default withKeyboardEvents(Profile)
```